# Find a Function from a limit. Homework

Tags: calculus

I don't understand this question, #6. Could someone please explain?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find similarity with the following one:
$$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h =: f'(a) $$
The more general solution: calculate the left hand side limit, and write up any $f$ functions and any $a$ numbers, such that $f'(a)$ is the calculated number.